# Will move to Search engine friendly URLs help or hurt an already good search engine ranking?

Tags: seo, content-management-system

Hi I'm moving a mostly static site with some dynamic asp.net pages into a new CMS. The CMS uses SEO friendly URLs while the old site used dynamic URLs ending in .aspx. The client is worried that this might somehow change their great Search Engine Rankings especially since the URLs will be a bit different now. I'm trying my best to keep the new URLs as close as possible to the originals but I'm wondering if this move will help or hurt with their SEO. Any ideas?

Comment: You will want to direct this question to [webmasters.se] as it is not about programming.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll ask there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will hurt their SEO badly if you don't implement 301 redirects properly. Otherwise you are safe.

There is one tricky corner case. If Google has released a recent algorithm update hurting their site, you may not see the impact yet, because pages have not been recrawled yet.

The migration could accelerate this recrawling and make the unavoidable happen faster. Don't assume the migration caused the drop in ranking in this case.